# Facebook iOS SDK 3.6 startWithGraphPath completion block not executed

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I've integrated with Facebook so that I can, among other things, post statuses to my feed. I  based some of my code off of the [publish to feed developer tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/). When running the following Graph API request from my iOS application the completion block of the request is never called and no error appears in the XCode debug log.

```
[FBRequestConnection
startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
parameters:params
HTTPMethod:@"POST"
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        DLog(@"error: domain = %@, code = %d", error.domain, error.code);
    } else {
        DLog(@"Posted action, id: %@", result[@"id"]);
    }
}];
```

I have two convenience functions that perform checks against the current `activeSession` before executing this request. They look like this:

```
+ (BOOL)facebookSessionIsOpen {
    return (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen);
}

+ (BOOL)facebookSessionHasPublishPermissions {
    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound ||
        [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound ||
        [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"manage_friendlists"] == NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Both of these functions return `YES` indicating an active session with the necessary publishing permission. What's more confusing is that I can pull the user's profile without issue after performing the same checks successfully (granted publishing permissions are not required to pull the profile) using the following code:

```
[FBRequestConnection
startWithGraphPath:@"me"
parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture,id,birthday,email,location,hometown" forKey:@"fields"]
HTTPMethod:@"GET"
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary* resultDict = (NSDictionary*)result;

    NSString* emailAddress = resultDict[@"email"];
    NSString* location = resultDict[@"location"][@"name"];
    NSString* birthday = resultDict[@"birthday"];
    NSString* homeTown = resultDict[@"hometown"][@"name"];
    ...
}];
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a threading one. The Facebook iOS SDK doesn't seem to like to execute a `FBRequest` on a different thread from the one that you called `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` on and promptly deadlocks. It turns out I was running the postStatus request in a separate thread like so:

```
dispatch_queue_t some_queue = dispatch_queue_create("some.queue.name", NULL);
dispatch_async(some_queue, ^{
    [FacebookHelper postStatusToFacebookUserWall:newStatus withImage:imageData];
}];
```

Make sure your `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` and any `FBRequest` permutations all happen on the same thread, or you'll likely run into these silent failures.